# div with background color, semi opacity and border has invisible border?

Tags: css

I have some divs like this:

[image]

- The second div has the class highlit
- The third div has the class framed
- The fourth div has both highlit and framed.

Why is the border disappearing in the fourth case?

http://jsfiddle.net/ycyrwgcz/3/

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="thumb"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            +
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="highlit thumb"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            +
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="framed thumb"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            =
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="highlit framed thumb"><div class="overlay"></div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with the css

```
body
{
    background-color: #ff8888;
}

.thumb
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #8888ff;
}

.overlay
{
    height: 100%;
}

.thumb.framed .overlay
{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumb.highlit .overlay
{
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the css rules you have:

```
.thumb.highlit .overlay {
  background-color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.thumb.framed .overlay {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
}
```

Now, for the 4th `<div>` both the above styles get mixed up. Means, there is a `background-color: #fff` along with `border: 2px solid #fff`.

As you can see, both these are white color. And because of this you're not able to distinguish the border.

Try to change the `color` of any one of the above rules and you'll get the solution.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want this, should be self explaining ;)

```
.thumb.highlit .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fxxf6kcs/1/

Answer (score 1):

It isn't disappearing - just blending in with the rest of the overlay and as you have set it to be opaque it will turn purple.  If you are only wanting the background to be opaque and not the whole overlay you will need to use rgba background colours:

```
.thumb.highlit .overlay
{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ycyrwgcz/4/)

[This should work back to ie 8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors)

Comment: But I see absolutely nothing of the border!

Comment: Did you check the example link above? there is a white border on the last box

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body
{
    background-color: #ff8888;
}

.thumb
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #8888ff;
}

.overlay
{
    height: 100%;
}

.thumb.framed 
{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumb.framed .overlay
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumb.highlit .overlay
{
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `background-color` and `border-color` is same (`#fff`) in the fourth div.

You are using `.overlay` class which has the following:

```
.thumb.highlit .overlay {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.thumb.framed .overlay {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```